# Power Query and Sharepoint slow refresh

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I am using power query to get data from a series of excel documents on SharePoint. However, my document is very slow to refresh. I read [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sharepoint-refresh-very-very-slow-optimized-the-query/td-p/1116596) that a possible cause could be the sheer number of documents within the SharePoint and the fact that the query scans every document within it. The last post on that page suggests connecting to the desired file directly via URL which is much quicker but doesn't work in my situation. The excel documents I am using are updated monthly and the first part of my query uses sorts to ensure I am using current information.

Have tested my query on local documents to ensure it is optimized enough and was satisfied with the speed of the refresh. Are there any other ways to speed up the process?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options I know of and use myself:

Option 1) Sync sharepoint to your local PC using the "sync" button on the sharepoint site. This uses OneDrive to sync the sharepoint folder to a folder on your PC. Then you can use power query to loop through the folder on your PC.

Option 2) Use Power Automate Cloud Flows to loop through the sharepoint folder once per day / week / month to find the most recent file. Save a copy of this file with a consistent name like "SourceFile_Current". Power Automate will overwrite that file with the most recent copy every time it runs. Then you can point Power Query to that single file, and it will not have to loop through the whole sharepoint site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have colleagues that will be using the file and the reason I am using SharePoint rather than a local source is so that they can use the file too. When I had local references the file would break when another user opened it and tried to refresh.

Comment: That doesn't happen when syncing with sharepoint. When you sync with sharepoint, the file stays on sharepoint, and you each have a local copy on your local PC.

Comment: If I use the synced SharePoint folder will this not contain a local reference and therefore create issues when my colleagues use the file?

Comment: Ah ok your colleagues will be using the file that contains the Power Query. I thought you meant they will also be using the source file. Yes you are correct, the local reference won't work for your colleagues.


The second option is probably better - to have a "current" version of the file that gets overwritten with the newest version, using either Power Automate or VBA. The benefit of using Power Automate is that it is easier to trigger it based on a schedule, or receipt of an email. With VBA you would typically need to run a macro manually.